# logging directory format?

Tags: python, logging

I want to log my test result one level above from where I am running the test. So I how do I do it without list out the entire path?

```
logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Doesn't this just reduce to *"how can I find the path of the currently-running file"*? In which case surely you can find that via Google.

Answer (score 2):

This was more than a trivial question for me to figure out - "via Google" yielded *many* options, but using your current code, here are two possible solutions:

- continue using [logging.basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig): the trivial solution would be add the relative path of the directory one level above to the filename. The pythonic and cross-platform way appears to be with [os.pardir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pardir):

```
import os
import logging

# setup the path to the logfile
logname = 'test.log'
logfile = os.path.join(os.pardir, logname)

# log as you are currently
logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

- Another option would be to use [logging.FileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler), which [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) state:

  > Handlers send the log records (created by loggers) to the appropriate
  >   destination.

  which in this case would be the location one level above from where you're running the test. Only difference is you'd use the newly created `logger` object:

```
#setup the logger object
logger = logging.getLogger('test')
fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# use the logger object
logger.debug('a DEBUG')
logger.info('an info')
```